# If we installed the package for all users, but we want the tabs access be removed from every profile, how can we achieve that?

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets, bulkification, bulk

My clients ask me.
If we installed the package for all users, but we want the tabs access be removed from every profile, how can we achieve that?

Is there any faster way rather than going manually through every and each profile and remove the access for tabs, objects and fields from it?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed package Bof Per Man and pushed it into AppExchange.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FtWcBUAV

It has separate tabs to mass add or mass remove permissions from selected profiles and permission sets to selected objects, fields and tabs.

The process of removal tab access may take awhile, but it is automated, so that you don't have to go over each and every profile manually and remove the access to particular tab or object of field.

Comment: An interesting offering. Did you open source it? I'm guessing not since the github repo is just for issue tracking.

Comment: @PhilW Do you think I should open source it? I have put it for free as a AppExchange package product despite I put a lof of efforts to build it and included a way to manage tab accesses in bulk...

Comment: I think it is a valuable tool (assuming it works as advertised). The benefit of open sourcing - people can submit bug fix or enhancement Pull Requests to you, so you don't have to write the code alone.

Comment: @PhilW, this is true, but for open source it is a big dilemma about choosing the correct license type to prevent someone else from publishing your package as a paid competitor application on AppExchange...